# Cruisecontrol Email Notification Task

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

i have a problem in ccnet email notification task, how to send mail for some person in **To Field**, for some person in **Cc field** and some more in **Bcc field**, the current email notification comes with only To field, for ex

```
<email from="raj.u@ccnet.com" mailhost="<somemailhost>" includeDetails="TRUE">
    <users>
      <user name="mark.s" group="buildmaster" address="mark.s@ccnet.com"/>
      <user name="david.b" group="buildmaster" address="david.b@ccnet.com"/>
      <user name="sally.t" group="buildmaster" address="sally.t@ccnet.com"/>
     <user name="raj.u" group="buildguru" address="raj.u@ccnet.com"/>
    </users>
```

Comment: Any body please help me!

Answer (score 0):

this is for the moment not possible,

but maybe you can bypass it by using mail groups / mail address at the mail server. So a mail sent to X, does a CC to Y and a BCC to Z.

Comment: Hi Williams, Thanks for your response, could you please explain a bit more with example

Comment: Make a mailgroup at the mail server called X
when a mail is sent to this group, it forwards/resends the mail to the original person expecting it, and also to the other ones.
This way the mail server does the logic of the cc and bcc functionality, and not ccnet.